# Query to identify gaps in IDs on a per terminal basis

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm pretty new to database programming.

I have a table that documents rows of transactions (each with a unique ID) - the unique ID is defined by the terminal/PC that is processing the transaction.

For example:

PC1 will start at 100 and the transactions it performs will go 101, 102, 103, 104 etc

PC2 will start at 200 and will go 201, 202, 203, 204 etc

All of which are in the same table, so the TransactionIDs are muddled (i.e the first entry will be for PC1, next two will be PC2 then another one for PC1 - this is due to them being ordered by timestamps)

I want to make a query that will display any gaps larger than 100 in the IDs but only for the IDs relevent to that PC (otherwise the results will display 101 and 204 as being a "gap")

Desired outcome would be the two IDs with a gap of 100 plus the timestamp and the PC name.

I've made a query similar to this before for finding the gap in timestamps, but unsure if the abvoe is as simple. here is that query:

```
WITH ordered AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) rn
    FROM Table1 
)
SELECT o1.ID id1, o1.DATE date1, o2.ID id2, o2.DATE date2, DATEDIFF(s, o1.date, o2.date) diff
  FROM ordered o1 JOIN ordered o2
    ON o1.rn + 1 = o2.rn 
 WHERE DATEDIFF(s, o1.date, o2.date) > 120
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Also, it will clearer if you include sample data and desired output.

Comment: I have to point out the flaw of what happens when a PC has more than 100 transactions, and they bleed into the other range? This is a bad idea in general.

Comment: I was just using that range as an example, the database I'm using has ID ranges of 15 digits, so bleeding into other ranges isn't an issue. I was just using three digit IDs for simplicity's sake

Comment: are your ids completely numeric, or are they alphanumeric?

Comment: Completely numeric, no letters at all

Comment: do you expect to have 1 gap, or do you want to be able to detect any number of gaps in IDs in the given range that are over a particular count threshold?

Comment: I expect to have gaps of between 1 and 20, that's expected and can be ignored. If there are gaps of >100 in the sequence for any of the PCs then there is a problem. So ideally it would be great to be able to detect any number of gaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with this, and adjust as needed.

I created a few variables that you can tweak for your circumstance which will define how far apart your ranges are.

Also, you're on the right track with a self join, I did a bit of math to find the IDs differing by more than 100.

Also, the selections for MinID and MaxID are just to show you how the formula works that is in the select below.

```
DECLARE @PCID INT = 1
DECLARE @PCOffset INT = 1000
DECLARE @GapThreshold INT = 100

--let's say we have 1 thousand between stations
SELECT MinID = (@PCID - 1) * @PCOffset

SELECT MaxID = (@PCID) * @PCOffset - 1

CREATE TABLE #IDs (
    MyID INT
    ,date_inserted DATETIME
    )

INSERT INTO #IDs (
    MyID
    ,date_inserted
    )
VALUES (    101 ,'1/1/2016' )
    ,(  102 ,'1/2/2016' )
    ,(  205 ,'1/3/2016' )
    ,(  1500    ,'1/3/2016' ) --out of range

;WITH ordered
AS (
    SELECT myRow = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY MyID
            )
        ,MyID
        ,date_inserted
    FROM #IDs
    WHERE MyID BETWEEN ((@PCID - 1) * @PCOffset)
            AND ((@PCID) * @PCOffset - 1)
    )
SELECT o1.MyID
    ,o1.date_inserted
    ,o2.MyID
    ,o2.date_inserted
FROM ordered o1
INNER JOIN ordered o2 ON o1.myRow + 1 = o2.myRow
WHERE o2.MyID - o1.MyID > @GapThreshold

DROP TABLE #IDs
```

Comment: Excellent, that works nicely thank you so much!
If I'm ever in the situation where getting the PCOffset isn't an option, how can I tweak the query to adapt to this?

For example; The IDs can sometimes come from thousands of seperate PCs all reading into one large database, finding the offset would be difficult given each one has a different range of numbers it uses up to 15 digits. So is it possible to run that query without needing to know the offset?

With the PCID and Gap Threshold, this lets me pull back any gaps of 100 in the IDs on a per PC basis, which is perfect.

Comment: @JMac  Youll need to provide some details regarding what your scheme for PCs is. You may need a separate table with the PC ID and starting and ending range so that you can query what your ranges are if you can't determine it mathematically. Also, please accept answer as well if it helped. :)

Comment: Ah right I see - I should be able to work around it, it's more a problem with our structure than anything. Cheers Jeremy!